# Magento2 : Multiple entries are creating in newsletter_subscriber table if i subscribe from different stores

Tags: magento2.2.6, newsletter-subscriber

I have 3 stores, If i subscribe from **English store** one entry will create with status as 1 in db.then I changed the store from English to **French** and subscribe to the newsletter, instead of update the same entry **new entry** is creating with status 1.How to fix this issue.**(Magento2.2.6 EE)**

Answer (score 0):

Pluginize/overwrite loadByCustomerData method and change select query where you need to remove store_id filter.

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/ResourceModel/Subscriber.php

```
/**
 * Load subscriber by customer
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
 * @return array
 */
public function loadByCustomerData(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer)
{
    $select = $this->connection
        ->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where('customer_id=:customer_id');

    $result = $this->connection
        ->fetchRow(
            $select,
            [
                'customer_id' => $customer->getId()
            ]
        );

    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    }

    $select = $this->connection
        ->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where('subscriber_email=:subscriber_email');

    $result = $this->connection
        ->fetchRow(
            $select,
            [
                'subscriber_email' => $customer->getEmail()
            ]
        );

    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    }

    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue by overwriting

`\Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber::loadByEmail()` in a custom module :

```
public function loadByEmail($subscriberEmail)
{    
    $select = $this->connection->select()->from($this->getMainTable())->where('subscriber_email=:subscriber_email AND store_id=:store_id');

    $result = $this->connection->fetchRow($select, ['subscriber_email' => $subscriberEmail,'store_id' => $this->getStoreId()]);

    if (!$result) {
        return [];
    }

    return $result;
}

protected function getStoreId() 
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```

**Reference :** https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13258